# Clear queues on bus start or stop

Tags: c#, integration-testing, publish-subscribe, rebus

Is there a configuration setting on Rebus to clear out the queues on bus startup or shutdown? The reason I need to do this is I have two instances of Rebus running for my integration test, and if a test fails I don't want the failed message to get retried in the subsequent test run.

Here is what I have for the integration test client that sends the messages. Note that RebusHost is just a wrapper around the system under test:

```
using Rebus.Configuration;
using Rebus.Transports.Msmq;

namespace MT.Testing.Integration
{
    [TestClass]
    public class IntegrationTestFixture
    {
        private static IMtHost _host;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void IntegrationTestInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
            _host = new RebusHost();

            _host.Start();
        }

        [AssemblyCleanup]
        public static void IntegrationTestCleanup()
        {
            _host.Stop();
        }

        public static IBus GetClientBus(IContainerAdapter containerAdapter)
        {
            return Configure.With(containerAdapter)
                .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("mt.testing.integration.client.input", "mt.testing.integration.client.error"))
                .MessageOwnership(d => d.Use(new IntegrationMessageOwnership()))
                .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInMemory())
                .Sagas(s => s.StoreInMemory())
                .CreateBus().Start();
        }
    }

    public class IntegrationMessageOwnership : IDetermineMessageOwnership
    {
        public string GetEndpointFor(Type messageType)
        {
            return "mt.testing.integration.input";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebus does not have an "official" API that does this, but you can do what I do in most of Rebus' MSMQ integrations tests: Use the helpful static methods of Rebus' `MsmqUtil` - e.g. like this: `MsmqUtil.PurgeQueue("mt.testing.integration.input")`

Comment: Thanks. That class was internal so I had to copy it into my utils project, with proper attribution of course.

Comment: Right, sorry! I forgot about that :(